# How to return a sublist of a list only containing certain numbers of the original list

Tags: python

I want to write code that returns if a list has values bigger than 
any number for example 4, but none that returns me only the values that go till 4 as a sublist.

I've already tried all the comparison operators, to make sure I'm using the right one, countless of different codes, etc.

```
if len(list) == 1:
        return list[0]
    else:
        return list[0] + sublist(list[1:])
```

another try:

```
if len(list) <4:
        return list[0]
```

the perfect output would be for example: 
for:
`sublist([1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8])`

it should return : 
`[1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: do you know how to use `for-loops`?

Comment: No , but I know how to use while loops , sorry

Comment: might be helpful if you look up how to use `for-loops` that would help you solve this problem in an understandable way, since the solution involves iterating over a list

Comment: Next time, don't bother writing so much irrelevant text in your question

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension.

```
return [x for x in mylist if x <= 4]
```

Comment: for a beginner, who doesn't even understand how to use `for-loops` this might not be the best answer

Comment: It worked . Thank you soo much . I would´ve never gotten to a  solution without you !

Comment: Oh and I just looked up what for loops are . Turns out I know what they are , I just didn´t know their name . Whoopsie ,

Comment: @aws_apprentice disagree, always write for the *future* reader not just the questioner. However, in this case it's clear that this answer can't be original